# Get subfield in flexible content layout

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

Seems that I can't get the value out off the field “overview_title” on line 29.  which is a subfield of the “overview_layout”. 
JSON: https://pastebin.com/BLBb6cjx.

I can get the “overview_layout” field. but its subfields won't return anything. anyone?

What I'm trying to do is to get the values of those 3 custom fields. But I get nothing.

This is what i'm trying in Timber:

````
$post = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $post;

$context['layout'] = get_field('cancer_type_layout');

$context['overview'] = array (
  'title' => get_field('overview_title'),
  'text' => get_field('overview_text'),
  'image' => get_field('overview_picture')
);

Timber::render('templates/pages/template-cancer.twig', $context);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [work with Flexible Content fields](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#flexible-content-field) in Timber, you **mustn’t access subfields** by more calls to `get_field()`. All data of the subfields is already there when you get the data with the name of the Flexible Content field.

```php
$post = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $post;

// Everything you need will be in block.
$context['block'] = $post->meta( 'cancer_type_layout' );

Timber::render( 'templates/pages/template-cancer.twig', $context );
```

In Twig, you can then access your data directly from the `block` variable:

```
{% if 'overview_layout' === block.acf_fc_layout %}
    {{ block.overview_title }}
    {{ block.overview_text }}
    {{ block.overview_picture }}
{% endif %}
```